# Deploying new version of a flutter app on robot(android robot)

Tags: android, flutter, deployment

I have worked with a robot which has Android as an operating system, I have deployed my flutter app on that robot.

I have cleared the cache, deleted all apk files, then I transfer an apk file for the new version but the robot just install the old version.

There are possible solutions??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.